# Is the Ad Hominem fallacy a version of the Genetic Fallacy?

Tags: fallacies

I'm not sure if this is on-topic, but it's an interesting question to me, though it may lack any real purpose.

The Ad Hominem fallacy is when someone takes where a claim or argument propagated from and draws conclusions based on the origin, not the argument itself.

Similarly, the Genetic Fallacy is when someone claims that because of the way a belief originated, it's wrong.

So kind of an odd question here, but what's the difference here?

Comment: [This site](https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/search) is helpful.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hominem#Types_of_ad_hominem_arguments) says that *ad hominem* is a type of genetic fallacy.  However, the person in *ad hominem* attacks need not be the origin of the claim or argument (she can just be a messenger), nor does *ad hominem* have to argue that the conclusion fails *because* the opponent is its origin. Conversely, the faulted origin in the genetic fallacy need not be a person (it can be a device or a document). There is considerable overlap in practice, but there is no inclusion in either direction, they are logically independent.